# Error in running C application with python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running c application with python code and my code is as follows.

```
import subprocess
import os
sourcepath = '/home/atic/deepstream/videos'
destpath = '/home/atic/deepstream/jsons'

avi_files = [f for f in os.listdir(sourcepath) if f.endswith('.avi')]
for file_ in avi_files:
    avi_file = os.path.join(sourcepath, file_)  
    json_file = os.path.join(destpath, file_.split('.avi')[0]+'.json')
    subprocess.run(['./deepstream-pose-estimation-app', '--input', avi_file, '--focal', '800.0', '--width', '1280', '--height', '720', '--fps', '--save-pose', json_file])
```

This line runs if I set

```
subprocess.run(['./deepstream-pose-estimation-app', '--input', 'tst.avi', '--focal', '800.0', '--width', '1280', '--height', '720', '--fps', '--save-pose', 'tst.json']
```

But video file name and json file name are always changing.
So I set string variables.
But `subprocess` doesn't accept.

The error is

```
--input value is not a valid URI address. Exiting...
```

How can I fix?

EDIT

```
import subprocess
import os
sourcepath = '/home/atic/deepstream/videos'
destpath = '/home/atic/deepstream/jsons'

avi_files = [f for f in os.listdir(sourcepath) if f.endswith('.avi')]
for file_ in avi_files:
    avi_file = os.path.join(sourcepath, file_)  
    json_file = os.path.join(destpath, file_.split('.avi')[0]+'.json')
    print(avi_file)
    print(json_file)
    subprocess.run(['./deepstream-pose-estimation-app', '--input', avi_file, '--focal', '800.0', '--width', '1280', '--height', '720', '--fps', '--save-pose', json_file])
```

print out these two lines

```
print(avi_file)
print(json_file)
```

Now the output is

```
/home/atic/deepstream/videos/sit_1059.avi
/home/atic/deepstream/jsons/sit_1059.json
--input value is not a valid URI address. Exiting...
Usage:
  deepstream-pose-estimation-app [OPTION?] Deepstream BodyPose3DNet App

Help Options:
  -h, --help                        Show help options
  --help-all                        Show all help options
  --help-gst                        Show GStreamer Options

Application Options:
  -v, --version                     Print DeepStreamSDK version.
  --version-all                     Print DeepStreamSDK and dependencies version.
  --input                           [Required] Input video address in URI format by starting with "rtsp://" or "file://".
  --output                          Output video address. Either "rtsp://" or a file path or "fakesink" is acceptable. If the value is "rtsp://", then the result video is published at "rtsp://localhost:8554/ds-test".
  --save-pose                       The file path to save both the pose25d and the recovered pose3d in JSON format.
  --conn-str                        Connection string for Gst-nvmsgbroker, e.g. <ip address>;<port>;<topic>.
  --publish-pose                    Specify the type of pose to publish. Acceptable value is either "pose3d" or "pose25d". If not specified, both "pose3d" and "pose25d" are published to the message broker.
  --tracker                         Specify the NvDCF tracker mode. The acceptable value is either "accuracy" or "perf". The default value is "perf"  "accuracy" mode requires DeepSORT model to be installed. Please refer to [Setup Official Re-ID Model](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/dev-guide/text/DS_plugin_gst-nvtracker.html) section for details.
  --fps                             Print FPS in the format of current_fps (averaged_fps).
  --fps-interval                    Interval in seconds to print the fps, applicable only with --fps flag.
  --width                           Input video width in pixels. The default value is 1280.
  --height                          Input video height in pixels. The default value is 720.
  --focal                           Camera focal length in millimeters. The default value is 800.79041.
  --osd-process-mode                OSD process mode CPU - 0 or GPU 1.
```

Comment: Print the values of `avi_file` and `json_file`. Are they correct?

Comment: Yes correct. They print correct path

Comment: If you run yourself, from the command-line in a shell in a terminal, with the actual arguments as printed by your program, does it work then? If you `cd` to the root directory and remove the leading slash `/` from the paths, does it work then?

Comment: I have added printing two paths. You can see the correct path. But `-input value is not a valid URI address. Exiting...` error is there.

Comment: Reading the help, `--input` seems to require "file://" in front of your path

Comment: Besides trying with absolute paths in a shell in a terminal (manual testing), why not simply *make* it an URI? Prepend `file://` before the path.

Comment: Yes you are right. I need file. Thanks. Now I write bash shell file.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows.

```
search_dir=/home/atic/deepstream/videos
dest_dir=/home/atic/deepstream/jsons/
substr=".avi"
dest_ext=".json"
filehead="file://"
for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
  IFS="/" read -ra my_array <<< "$entry"
  for element in "${my_array[@]}"; do
     if [[ $element == *"$substr"* ]];
        
    then
       IFS="." read -ra second_array <<< $element
       jsonpath="${dest_dir}${second_array}${dest_ext}"
       echo $jsonpath
       echo "${filehead}${entry}"
       ./deepstream-pose-estimation-app --input "${filehead}${entry}" --focal 800.0 --width 1280 --height 720 --fps --save-pose $jsonpath
       
     fi
  done
done
```

Comment: bash file is easier